# How do I get specific ID in data list from database?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to get specific `id` from database but from some reasons I get null in `id`.

In page load :

```
string id = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["myCart"] == null)
    {
        myCart = new Cart();
        Session["myCart"] = myCart; 
    }

    string id = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
    int id2 = this.DataList1.SelectedIndex;
    myCart = (Cart)Session["myCart"];

    DataTable dt = ds.SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Products where ProductID = '" + id + "'");
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

    myCart.Insert(new CartItem(int.Parse(id), row["ProductName"].ToString(), int.Parse(row["UnitPrice"].ToString()), 1));
}
```

Comment: That's cause `Request.QueryString["ProductID"]` is `null`

Comment: @Rahul But what is the problem in `Request.QueryString["ProductID"]` how i get the id without null

Comment: You aren't passing any query string value

Comment: @Rahul and what does it means??

Comment: how does your URL look like?

Comment: @G_S `http://localhost:64380/Phone.aspx`

Comment: your url should look like this `http://localhost:64380/Phone.aspx?ProductID=123`

Comment: In your URL, you dont have any querystring with name ProductID. And so querying with null against database, you are not getting a valid value. A valid url in this case would be http://localhost:64380/Phone.aspx?ProductID=12345

Comment: but in the shop there are many products. so how in the url will be the id of all of them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I would suggest is: add the below link button to your item template

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="select">Select</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then handle the `SelectedIndexChange` event in code file:

```
protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = DataList1.SelectedIndex;
    //Your product id should be bound to a label in the item template
    Label lbl = (Label)DataList1.Items[index].FindControl("IDoftheControlcontainingid");
    string id=lbl.Text;

    //use the id variable to get the product and add to cart. your old code
    if (Session["myCart"] == null)
    {
        myCart = new Cart();
        Session["myCart"] = myCart; 
    }

    myCart = (Cart)Session["myCart"];

    DataTable dt = ds.SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Products where ProductID = '" + id + "'");
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

    myCart.Insert(new CartItem(int.Parse(id), row["ProductName"].ToString(), int.Parse(row["UnitPrice"].ToString()), 1));
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to move another page. i want to fill my shopping cart and when i press on the cart.aspx it will show me all the items that in the cart

Comment: may be i am not understanding your question. but you can't get anything from query string until you pass something into it.

Comment: so  you can help me get the id from database ? i want the selected item from data list id that will be selected

Comment: try the above solution .